# Can we calculate number expressions in the string without loop statements (by regex)?

Tags: java, regex, string

JDK 7.
What is regex way to process str1 and get square of all inside numbers?

```
String str1="ab cd 2 4 ef 12x";
...
System.out.println(str1.replaceAll("...", "..."));
```

Can we get console out as

```
ab cd 4 16 ef 144x
```

without loop using?

Perhaps it so complex or impossible... unfortunately, I don't know.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: regex is about pattern matching, and string substitution, not computation.

Comment: This is not Perl where you have `/e` modifier. Use a `Matcher#appendReplacement` with a regex that matches numbers, and perform the calculations inside the `while (m.find())` block.

Comment: You could use the Streams API, to decode all the words/numbers, square the numbers and join the resulting string.

Comment: This does not constitute 'calculat[ing] number expressions in a string'. It constitutes finding numbers in a string and applying a fixed calculation to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to do that in one `replaceAll` call, or even two, because the substrings matched cannot be evaluated on the fly (you could do that in Perl, but not in Java).

So, as I mentioned, a workaround is to use the `Matcher#appendReplacement` with the loop.

See a [sample demo](http://ideone.com/H2EtRT):

```
String s = "ab cd 2 4 ef 12x";
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(result,
      String.valueOf((int)Math.pow(Double.parseDouble(m.group(0)), 2))); // Calculate
}
m.appendTail(result);
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

I have an solution with loop , may be its help you to find other solutions

```
String str="ab cd 2 4 ef 12x";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(Math.pow(Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)), 2));
}
```

Output : 
4.0
16.0
144.0